# HTML 5 Canvas not working in my project, but same code works in JSFiddle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, html5-canvas

This question has been asked before, but none of the answers are relevant to me.

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jabark/j6nDN/4/

On my local web project, all I get is a blank screen.

I have no idea what the problem is, here is what I've tried:

1) Putting it within a DOM Ready function.
2) Putting the code within body tag beneath the relevant canvas.
3) Give the relevant elements the same ID's as the fiddle.
4) Put both sections of JS Code into WinMerge to make sure absolutely identical.
5) Put some basic canvas code in (which worked).

Here's my relevant code in my project:

```
<article id="testmm" class="mindmap relative SectionStyle3">
   <canvas id="cv" data-cloudnum="7" class="col col1"></canvas>
   <img id="scream" class="center hide" src="/Images/logo.png" alt="" />
   <img class="cloud hide" src="/Images/clouds/1.png" alt="" />

   <script>    
      var MaxCircles = 7;

      var ctx = $('#cv').get(0).getContext('2d');
      var img = document.getElementById("scream");
      var imgHeight = $("#scream").height();
      var imgWidth = $("#scream").width();

      var TotalHeight = $('#cv').height()
      var TotalWidth = $('#cv').width()
      var CanvasCentre = { x: Math.floor(TotalWidth / 2), y: Math.floor(TotalHeight / 2) };

      var circles = new Array();
      for (var i = 0; i < MaxCircles; i++) {
         circles[i] = { x: 50, y: 50, r: 2 }
      }

      var mainCircle = { x: CanvasCentre.x, y: CanvasCentre.y, r: 2 };

      function drawCircle(data) {
         ctx.beginPath();
         ctx.arc(data.x, data.y, data.r, 0, Math.PI * 2);
         ctx.fill();
      }
      function drawLine(from, to) {
         ctx.beginPath();
         var newX = from.x + (from.width / 2);
         var newY = from.y + (from.height / 2);
         ctx.moveTo(newX, newY);

         //Make Curve Line
         var CentreX = (newX + to.x) / 2
         var CentreY = (newY + to.y) / 2
         var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 60) - 29);
         if (y == 0) { y = -30 };
         CentreX += y;
         y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 60) - 29);
         if (y == 0) { y = -30 };
         CentreY += y;
         ctx.quadraticCurveTo(CentreX, CentreY, to.x, to.y);

         //Make Straight Line
         //ctx.lineTo(to.x, to.y);

         ctx.stroke();
      }

      function canvasImage(x, y, h, w, img) {
         this.image = img;
         this.x = x;
         this.y = y;
         this.width = w;
         this.height = h;
         return this;
      }

      var canvasImage1 = new canvasImage(CanvasCentre.x, CanvasCentre.y, 0, 0, img);

      drawCircle(mainCircle);

      $.each(circles, function (index) {
         // Make them circle around the middle
         var yradius = CanvasCentre.y
         var xradius = CanvasCentre.x
         yradius -= this.r;
         xradius -= this.r;
         var y = CanvasCentre.y + yradius * Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * (index + 1) / circles.length);
         var x = CanvasCentre.x + xradius * Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * (index + 1) / circles.length);
         this.x = x
         this.y = y

         drawCircle(this);
         drawLine(canvasImage1, this);
      });

      ctx.drawImage(img, CanvasCentre.x - (imgWidth / 2), CanvasCentre.y - (imgHeight / 2), 100, 100);

   </script>
</article>
```

Comment: How did you include jquery on your local project?

Comment: Do you have proper `<!DOCTYPE html>` "and so on"?

Comment: @Rikonator Can I not have a fluid canvas then?

Comment: @user3008011 Jquery is working. I have a JQuery slideshow working but I did: `<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js">`

Comment: @pstenstrm Yes I checked that too

Comment: @JamieBarker Have you tried disabling other scripts such as that slideshow? Might be something conflicting there.

Comment: @user3008011 I don't think so. I just tried running the code directly into my firebug console and it did it. I just doesn't seem to want to work on the initial page load **:/**. If something was conflicting, it wouldn't work in console AFAIK.

Comment: Although that only worked once I had given it a height and width. So Rikonator was correct. Shame he deleted his comment...

Comment: So your problem is fixed with his sollution then now? You can always answer your own question offcourse.

Comment: You have to wait two days to accept your own answer to your own question... written answer anyway **:)**. Thanks to all for assisting me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It didn't work because I didn't include a height and width on the canvas element. Someone (Rikonator) gave this answer in a comment but then deleted it **:/**.

To make it a responsive design canvas I'm having to use a window resize function to resize the canvas and then re-populate it again.

*"If web design was simple, everyone would be doing it"*...

Comment: Although my suggestion worked, I deleted my comment because I checked the specification after just to make sure. It states that if the `width` and `height` attributes are missing, they should default to `300` and `150` respectively. In fact, you can observe that the default values *are* used in this fiddle; http://jsfiddle.net/3SV7W/.

Comment: Interesting, and weird... I must have had something causing it to not use the default then **:/**

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine for me. The only thing I can do to break it (outside changing your code on the jsFiddle) is to not load jQuery. Very that your jQuery is loading correctly. I'll post my working version of your code with a jQuery loading from a CDN so there's no doubt. The broken images are of course because they are local to you. Just to clarify, I changed none of your code within the body tags.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <article id="testmm" class="mindmap relative SectionStyle3">

      <canvas id="cv" data-cloudnum="7" class="col col1"></canvas>
      <img id="scream" class="center hide" src="/Images/logo.png" alt="" />
      <img class="cloud hide" src="/Images/clouds/1.png" alt="" />

      <script>
        var MaxCircles = 7;

        var ctx = $('#cv').get(0).getContext('2d');
        var img = document.getElementById("scream");
        var imgHeight = $("#scream").height();
        var imgWidth = $("#scream").width();

        var TotalHeight = $('#cv').height()
        var TotalWidth = $('#cv').width()
        var CanvasCentre = { x: Math.floor(TotalWidth / 2), y: Math.floor(TotalHeight / 2) };

        var circles = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < MaxCircles; i++) {
          circles[i] = { x: 50, y: 50, r: 2 }
        }

        var mainCircle = { x: CanvasCentre.x, y: CanvasCentre.y, r: 2 };

        function drawCircle(data) {
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.arc(data.x, data.y, data.r, 0, Math.PI * 2);
          ctx.fill();
        }
        function drawLine(from, to) {
          ctx.beginPath();
          var newX = from.x + (from.width / 2);
          var newY = from.y + (from.height / 2);
          ctx.moveTo(newX, newY);

          //Make Curve Line
          var CentreX = (newX + to.x) / 2
          var CentreY = (newY + to.y) / 2
          var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 60) - 29);
          if (y == 0) { y = -30 };
          CentreX += y;
          y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 60) - 29);
          if (y == 0) { y = -30 };
          CentreY += y;
          ctx.quadraticCurveTo(CentreX, CentreY, to.x, to.y);

          //Make Straight Line
          //ctx.lineTo(to.x, to.y);

          ctx.stroke();
        }

        function canvasImage(x, y, h, w, img) {
          this.image = img;
          this.x = x;
          this.y = y;
          this.width = w;
          this.height = h;
          return this;
        }

        var canvasImage1 = new canvasImage(CanvasCentre.x, CanvasCentre.y, 0, 0, img);

        drawCircle(mainCircle);

        $.each(circles, function (index) {
          // Make them circle around the middle
          var yradius = CanvasCentre.y
          var xradius = CanvasCentre.x
          yradius -= this.r;
          xradius -= this.r;
          var y = CanvasCentre.y + yradius * Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * (index + 1) / circles.length);
          var x = CanvasCentre.x + xradius * Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * (index + 1) / circles.length);
          this.x = x
          this.y = y

          drawCircle(this);
          drawLine(canvasImage1, this);
        });

        ctx.drawImage(img, CanvasCentre.x - (imgWidth / 2), CanvasCentre.y - (imgHeight / 2), 100, 100);

      </script>
    </article>

  </body>
</html>
```